# Why does fetch_profile_card return nothing when using Dota2 Python API?

Tags: python, api, gevent

I'm using the [dota2 python library](https://dota2.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide.html) to gather data from the Dota2 game client. Using [the initial example](https://dota2.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide.html#fetch-player-profile-card) I use the provided function:

```
@dota.on('ready')
def fetch_profile_card():
    jobid = dota.request_profile_card(70388657)
    profile_card = dota.wait_msg(jobid, timeout=10)

    if profile_card:
        print (str(profile_card) )
```

As I understand gevent - the way to invoke the above function is like so:

```
dota.on('ready',fetch_profile_card)
```

When I do this nothing happens. No error but the response is None.

Some additional context:

I have logging at DEBUG

```
logging.basicConfig(format='[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s %(name)s: %(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG)
```

When I log in I *do* see some output
[image]
But when I run `dota.on('ready',fetch_profile_card)` I get nothing

Comment: can you check for value of   `jobid`

Comment: I think you're passing wrong `accountId`

Comment: @RishabhKumar the value of jobid is job_1

Comment: Why do you think that @AdamStrauss? That's the exact same account id as used in their example.